# Why apk size increase in different android version

Tags: android, apk

I create a simple application and size of .apk generated by android studio is 1 MB, then i installed in `android 2.3` version size increased to 3.48 MB , then i installed in `android 5.0` version size increase to 5.48 MB.

My Question is only that why size of apk in increased in different version.

Comment: That's barely a programming question asked simply for curiosity purposes. Any actual technical data given here will make zero difference in any developer work.